# "out of range" else clause causes syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check the value range of an input number, then print the correct "size" (small, medium or large). If the value is out of my acceptable range, then I want the `else` statement to print out that the number is not valid.

Minimal example for my problem:

```
n = int(input("number= "))
if 0 <= n < 5:
    a = "small"
if 5 <= n < 10:
    a = "medium"
if 10 <= n <= 20:
    a = "large"
print("this number is",a)
else:
    print("thats not a number from 0 to 20")
```

According to Google, this is a problem with indentation.  I've tried multiple ways of indenting this; I can fix the syntax, but I can't get the logic correct.

Comment: you have a print statement between your last `if` and the `else`. remove that and you'll be fine

Comment: `else` needs to be followed by an `if`. It cannot be by itself. You can move the `print("this number is",a)` to be after your `else`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Other way around.  `else` needs to follow an `if` or `elif`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh My bad, that's what I mean't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's fix your immediate issue: you have an `else` with no corresponding `if` statement.  Syntactically, this is because you have an intervening "out-dented" statement, the `print`, which terminates your series of `if`s.

Logically, this is because you have two levels of decision: "Is this a number 0-20?", and "Within that range, how big is it?"  The problem stems from writing only one level of `if`s to make this decision.  To keep close to your intended logic flow, write a general `if` on the outside, and encapsulate your small/medium/large decision and print within that branch; in the other branch, insert your "none of the above" statement:

```
n = int(input("number= "))
if 0 <= n <= 20:
    if n < 5:
        a = "small"
    elif n < 10:
        a = "medium"
    else:
        a = "large"
    print("this number is", a)    
else:
    print("that's not a number from 0 to 20")
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Others tried to fix the indentation in the code but like I said that didn't really fix the issue, it just removed the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the code edits.  This isn't my best focus day.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like

```
n = int(input("number= "))
if 0 <= n < 5:
    a = "small"
elif 5 <= n < 10:
    a = "medium"
elif 10 <= n <= 20:
    a = "large"
else:
    a = "not a number from 0 to 20"

print("this number is",a)
```

Comment: This works! Unfortunately in my actual code I cannot assign the variable "a" to the else function. I did find help with a workaround though.

Comment: what do you mean `I cannot assign the variable "a" to the else function`? the posted code does exactly what you're asking for; when I input `22`, I get the output: `('this number is', 'not a number from 0 to 20')`

Comment: What I mean is the variable "a" wasn't originally under the else function. For this particular problem I created for the sake of understanding, your workaround is valid, but in my actual code that I have, I cannot assign the variable because it wouldn't make out a coherent sentence like it does here. For instance in this problem if I wanted the else statement to say "Can you not count to 20?"

Answer (score 1):

The print statement before the `else` statement needs to either be removed or indented to match:

```
a= "large"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've syntax (indentation) error:

```
n = int(input("number= "))
if 0 <= n < 5:
    a = "small"
if 5 <= n < 10:
    a = "medium"
if 10 <= n <= 20:
    a = "large"
#print("this number is",a) indentation error in this line
else:
    print("thats not a number from 0 to 20")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the print statement.

It is indented on the same level as the if block and thus, the if block ends on line containing the print statement.

Thus, the else on the next line is incorrect.

To achieve what you are trying, you should do something like this:

```
n = int(input("number= "))
if 0 <= n < 5:
    a = "small"
elif 5 <= n < 10:
    a = "medium"
elif 10 <= n <= 20:
    a = "large"
else:
    print("not between 0 and 20")

print("The number is", a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also use following code

```
n = int(input("number= "))

if 10 <= n <= 20:
    a = "large"
    print("this number is",a)
elif 5 <= n < 10:
    a = "medium"
    print("this number is",a)
elif 0 <= n < 5:
    a = "small"
    print("this number is",a)
else:
    print("thats not a number from 0 to 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

The print statement needs to be placed **after** the else block. Also, its best to use *elif* statements than *if* statements in a situation like this.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 20: "))
if 0 <= n <= 5:
    a = "small."
elif n <= 10:
    a = "medium."
elif n <= 20:
    a = "large."
else:
    a = "invalid / out of range."
print("This number is ", a)
```